# How can I sort timestamp data by redesigned case groups in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have one dataset below:

[image]

I would like to make Case_List which is categorized by Case ID, and Events which is sorted by Action Time.

Case ID should be counted from 0, and Events should be oragnized between ' [ ] .'

How can I sort timestamp data by redesigned case groups in Pandas as below?

[image]

Lastly, I would like to first action time and last action time in each case ID.

Is there useful function to do these things?

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df['Action Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Action Time'])

df = (df.sort_values(['Case Id','Action Time'])
        .groupby('Case Id')['Process']
        .agg(list)
        .reset_index(name='Events'))
```

For first an last times use:

```
df = (df.sort_values(['Case Id','Action Time'])
        .groupby('Case Id')['Process']
        .agg(Events = ("Process": list),
             First_time = ("Action Time": "first"),
             Last_time = ("Action Time": "last"))
        .reset_index())
```

Answer (score 0):

To improve the answer by jezrael, extract the letter of the process and get the first and last event:

```
df['Action Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Action Time'])

df['Process'] = df['Process'].str.split(" ").str[-1]

df = df.sort_values(['Case Id','Action Time']
        ).groupby('Case Id'
        ).agg(Events = ("Process", list),
             First = ("Process", "first"),
             Last = ("Process", "last"), )
```